# How to use a span with Inline css in a link in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp

I am new in cakephp and in my layout I wanna use this code...

```
<a href="#">Home<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs"></span></a>
```

how can I use Html helper to rewrite it?
for example like this code :
`echo $this->Html->link('Home',['controller'=>'users','action'=>'home']);` instead that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the 'escape'=>false option to your link makes it so it doesn't try to translate ('escape') all your html characters.

```
echo $this->Html->link(
        $this->Html->tag('span', 'Home', array(
            'class' => 'pull-right hidden-xs',
            'style' => 'font-size:16px;'
                )
        )
        , '#'
        , array(
    'escape' => false // Notice Here
        )
);
```